# How to put measures on X-axis and on Y-axis

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

i'm trying to create simple bar chart in Tableau.
Here example of my table :

### country | emissions | population

ES      | 3000  | 46M

FR      | 6000  | 66M

I want to put value in Y-axis, population in X-axis and the country label associated in the top of each bar. But i cannot do that (Tableau don't allow measures in Y axis and X axis, only one measure is allow).

Here an example of result I have : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlzJA.png)

The problem is that in the Y-axis, I cannot put measure so I convert emissions as dimension but i can't sort by crescent order. And I don't have solutions in order to put each country associated on the top of eache bar...

Here my data (not huge) : https://sendeyo.com/show/a73c58538d

Thanks for advance !

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to make a scatter plot. Tableau does allow you to put measures on both Rows and Columns. If you post a sample workbook or data, we are able to assist better.
 https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/buildexamples_scatter.htm

Comment: Bar charts don't have two value axes by definition (unlike scatter charts). If you want to *annotate* a bar chart with a label containing a value other than the value of the bar, then that is easy: just drag the value you want to the label shelf.

Comment: Thx @Bernardo, I edit my post whit a link to my data!

Comment: Ok @matt_black, so it's better in my case to do a scatter plot ? It work fine with scatter plot, I succeeded to do that!

Comment: @MoussCzn In short, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

[image: Bar chart, two axis]

Or

[image: Bar chart, one axis]

[Link to sample.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmis0amzohon1ou/210804_stack_question.twbx?dl=0)